# Load DB results using PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, database, arrays

I'm trying to load in a table on html the fields of my DB. I'm using PHP for select query that returns a json to put the values in table using javascript.
My question, how can I put the DB fields into an array to pass it to Javascript?
Thanks.

Comment: You don't need js at all to do this unless you're updating the page dynamically using AJAX. Either way without your code there isn't much anyone can do to help you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to load content from database to your html page. In your request you can just use the php script only to make your table.

```
 <table>
 <?php
  $query = mysql_query('YOUR QUERY');
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>

     <tr><td><?php echo $row['YOUR FIELD NAME']; ?></td></tr>

  <?php } ?>
  </table>
```